# What is Implicit for needed in firstCompletedOf in Scala

Tags: scala, future, implicit

**QUESTION**

That's an excerpt from `scala.concurrent.Future`

```
  def firstCompletedOf[T](futures: TraversableOnce[Future[T]])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
    val p = Promise[T]()
    val completeFirst: Try[T] => Unit = p tryComplete _
    futures foreach { _ onComplete completeFirst }
    p.future
  }
```

My question is, why do we need an implicit `ExecutionContext` in here? What does it do in this scope?

**BACKGROUND**

Switching from Java to Python I was upset by the fact that the following is not a correct Python program:

```
print("some string" + 42)
```

You have to add the explicit conversion, so this will work:

```
print("some string " + str(42))
```

Then, I started to program in Scala, and somehow the implicits started to be my nightmare:

I have read quite a few articles ([this](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html) one being the best) on implicits and I am still not convinced, why do we need implicits in scala!?

In my opinion, in the long term implicits make your code difficult to understand.

Since switching to scala I started to really like "explicits" (even though I really do like scala).

Could anyone point me to any other great resource on the topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that specific context, the `onComplete` callback requires an execution context.

```
def onComplete[U](f: (Try[T]) ⇒ U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

The intuition is that we need computation resources to execute the logic in the closure of the callback once the Future has completed in its own execution context.

As for the general discussion on `implicits`, they are a powerful tool. Quoting Ben Parker, *"with great power, comes great responsibility"*

Answer (score 2):

A great resources is actually scala own [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).

In firstCompletedOf the execution context is the responsible for the computations of the futures.

Comment: I would like the answer to be more specific, that is, what ExecutionContext provides to this scope - an equivalent of the `str(_)` in my Python example

Comment: Which context you should use is depending on you problem. You can always fall back to scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global, which are backed by a ForkJoinPool, but if you are using it in a bigger project with many async computaions, you should properly use your own execution context, which for test and development purposes could be the standard context.